# Haskell, creating a structured datatype

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I would like to create a structure datatype called *Structured* that can be used to represent *String, Int* and *List*. For example, structure is like: [*Int*, *String*, *Int*,[*Int*]].

Question 1: how to create this datatype?

```
data Structured = ...
```

Question 2: A function called *Confirm* that confirms the input satisfies a restriction, and has the signature type of *confirm:: Restriction -> Structure ->Maybe Bool*

Comment: Is this homework? What have you tried?

Comment: What possible restrictions are there? What does the `Maybe Bool` result from `confirm` mean? What does `Nothing` mean in this context, and how is this different from what `Just True` and `Just False` mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
data Structured = Structured Int String Int [Int]
```

would work.

```
confirm :: (Structured -> Bool) -> Structured -> Bool
```

seems a more sensible type, but has a trivial implementation as `id`.

I don't think you would need to return `Maybe Bool` from a valudation function - `Maybe a` is good for when you usually resturn an `a`, but sometimes don't. (It's good for very simple error handling, for example - give `Nothing` if there was an error.) In this case, you can always make a conclusion as to whether your input was valid, so you can always give back `True` or `False` - no need for the `Maybe`.

Perhaps you could have something like

```
confirm :: (String -> Bool) -> (Int -> Bool) -> Structured -> Bool
confirm okString okInt (Structured int1 string int2 ints) =
       all okInt (int1:int2:ints) && okString string
```

Here `int1:int2:ints` is the list that has `int1` in front of `int2` in front of `ints`.

A slightly nicer way of defining Structured would be:

```
data Structured = Structured {
           length ::Int,
           name   ::String,
           width  ::Int,
           somenumbers :: [Int]}
```

then you'd have

```
confirm :: (String -> Bool) -> (Int -> Bool) -> Structured -> Bool
confirm okString okInt s =
       all okInt (length s:width s:somenumbers s) && okString (name s)
```

It does the same job as the first data declaration, but gives you functions for getting at the internals.